# Wordpress ACF - Custom filter by Select Field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function that adds a new field to order by on WooCommerce. I would like to display the result for products that have the 'bestseller' select box checked.
ACF:
[image]

```php
function cw_add_postmeta_ordering_args( $args_sort_cw ) {
     
    $cw_orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    switch( $cw_orderby_value ) {
        case 'bestseller':
            $args_sort_cw['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            $args_sort_cw['order'] = 'desc';
            $args_sort_cw['meta_key'] = 'bagdes';
            $args_sort_cw['meta_value'] = 'bestseller'; 
            break;
    }
    return $args_sort_cw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the coed using a `'meta_query'` with the corrected ACF field key '`badges`', and adjusted sorting parameters that have the '`bestseller`' select box checked, hope that helps

```
function cw_add_postmeta_ordering_args( $args_sort_cw ) {
    $cw_orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean($_GET['orderby']) :
        apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'));

    switch ($cw_orderby_value) {
        case 'bestseller':
            $args_sort_cw['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            $args_sort_cw['order'] = 'DESC';
            $args_sort_cw['meta_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'badges', //Ensure this is your correct ACF field key
                    'value'   => 'bestseller',
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            );
            break;
    }

    return $args_sort_cw;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'cw_add_postmeta_ordering_args');
```